# A solution that uses EntityFramework source projects instead its assemblies, could not start successfully

Tags: c#, entity-framework, configuration, .net-4.0, app-config

I have a `WinForm`s project that uses `EntityFramework 6.1.2-beta` with `.NET4`, it worked fine, till I decided to replace `EF` assemblies with their source codes, for some tracing goals, so I removed `EntityFramework.dll` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` from my project references and get their source codes from [CodePlex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) and add them to my solution.

I changed these new project configuration to `DebugNet40`(because my project works with `.NET 4`, but `EntityFramework` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer` projects work with `.NET 4.5`).

It compile successfully, but now when I want to run my project I get following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)

It is my `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <section name="entityFramework" 
              type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
              EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
              PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
     <defaultConnectionFactory 
          type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, 
                EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
             <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
          </parameters>
     </defaultConnectionFactory>
     <providers>
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
               type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, 
               EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
     </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="ERPContext" 
                connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDb;
                Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=*****" 
                providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I removed `PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"` from `app.config` too, but the problem exists yet.

Is there any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Entity Framework source code is configured to produce delay-signed assemblies (which means they're marked as "should be signed in the future with the official key"). The official instructions at [Entity Framework's GitHub page](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/wiki/Building-the-Runtime) show how to disable strong name validation (run the `EnableSkipStrongNames` task: `build /t:EnableSkipStrongNames`), so that you can use the delay-signed assemblies without anyone having to release their private key. This is sufficient for development systems.

If you intend to release a product relying on your custom-built modified Entity Framework DLLs, you should generate a new key, and modify the EF source code to use that new key.

Comment: @Jarekczek Thanks for the edit, documentation is available on the new GitHub wiki, updated some more.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click the project in Visual Studio solution explorer, and Signing on the left and uncheck sign assembly. In your web config you will also need to remove the public key token.